# Capybara with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara

I just started creating test with capybara and I am facing a problem already.

So I have a before do which is creating a row in the DB with a value.

```
  @word = Word.create :word => 'bed'
```

After that I test to see if on a page I can find that row.
Further I test if create action is working:

```
    visit keywords_path
    fill_in  'Word', :with => 'work'
    click_button 'Create Word'

    current_path.should == word_path(@word)
    page.should have_content 'work'
```

And I get this failing test

```
creates a new word
 Failure/Error: current_path.should == word_path(@word)
   expected: "/words/1"
        got: "/words/2" (using ==)
```

I understand where is the problem, but how can I check the path against the new created row?

Comment: query your database for latest record and get the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know it will always be the last one, try:

```
Word.last
```